# Windows 7 Recovery Disk not working

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, laptop

Ive been having a bit of trouble with my windows 7 Toshiba laptop computer lately. It started with my computer running slow one evening so I tried to restart it but when it started up, it blue screened for half a second and shut off. I tried repeating this but it just kept happening. I tried going into the F12 menu to reset it but it didnt work that way either. It just showed the windows logo startup thing and then went to a black screen with my cursor still sitting there. After I tried that, restarting it showed a black screen that said

"
Intel UNDI, PXE-2.0 (build 083)
Copyright (c) 1997-2000   Intel Coporation

For Atheros PCIE Ethernet Controller v2.1.1.2(09/06/12)

Check cable connection!
PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel PXE ROM.

Reboot and select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key
"

So I got my Toshiba recovery media disk to try and fix it that way. It goes through and loads up fine, but it just shows a Windows logo and then eventually a little loading graphic and goes straight to a black screen. The recovery media disk that I have says "Toshiba Recovery Media Satelite S50 - A series Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit. I hope someone here knows a solution to this because I really cant afford to take this to a repair shop

Comment: Your question asks how to recover Windows 7 but your recovery media is Windows 8? This does not make sense.

Comment: It's what came with my laptop when I bought it. It has information about downgrading to windows 7 with the instructions but I can't even get the disk to work so :l

Comment: What is the current operating system, 8.1 or 7 (you indicate you tried to downgrade but couldn't)?  If you downgraded to 7, you might not be able to restore either 7 or 8.1 with the 8.1 recovery disk (just guessing).  The message is odd and irrelevant unless a network connection is the only defined boot option.  Try downloading and burning the Hirem boot CD on another computer. http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd   This is a free bootable diagnostic treasure trove that might help you figure out what the underlying problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the fact that you are using the wrong disk to rebuild, unless you want to install Windows 8.1 instead of Windows 7, it sounds like your hard drive is bad and needs to be replaced. The hint for me was the Intel network boot device message.

Do you hear any clicking or crunching sounds when you start up the machine?

There are ways to confirm this, outside of that message or "off sounds", including system diagnostics which are sometimes built into your laptop's BIOS as some makes and models have it and some don't.

If you have such a thing on your system, you can run the tests to confirm that the drive is working properly and if it is not it will produce an error code you can use when you talk to a technical support representative. So once you do this, contact the manufacturer or reseller, if you have a service agreement with them, and get a replacement disk before attempting to install again.

Comment: I havent been hearing any clicking or crunching sounds when I start up the machine. I dont think that it has any way to test the hard drive either. It does recognize the Hard Drive though because in the bios it has "TOSHIBA MQO1ABD100" listed

Comment: Listen carefully anyway... Sometimes a dying drive will click repeatedly as it retries the reading of the sectors. The drive might be recognizable, but it could still be bad. Sorry to hear that your BIOS doesn't have a diagnostic test. It's hard to tell without looking at the machine. Try here for some drive tests: http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Drivers-and-Utilities/Toshiba-hard-drive-diagnostic/td-p/517897